# Why URLConnection.setReadTimeout(0) function fetch data without error?

Tags: java, url

```
URLConnection.setReadTimeout(0)
```

function works properly but

```
URLConnection.setReadTimeout(10)
```

doesn't. why??

Comment: setReadTimeout(0) is documented as infinite timeout.  Do you mean something else?  If yes, please ask a clearer question.

Answer (score 0):

From: developer.android.com

public void setReadTimeout (int timeoutMillis)
Sets the maximum time to wait for an input stream read to complete before giving up. Reading will fail with a SocketTimeoutException if the timeout elapses before data becomes available. The default value of **0** disables read timeouts; read attempts will **block indefinitely**.

```
setReadTimeout(0) == block indefinitely (Or until read buffer is full)

setReadTimeout(10) == return Exception, after 10 mili sec, if buffer isn't full
```